# Spring View Resolver returning 404

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Baffled as to why I'm encountering problems with this new project.
Simply trying to ensure that Spring returns jsp files with a certain name within a specific directory whenever a Controller returns a string that defines the name of the jsp file.

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String test2(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("Returning test.jsp");
        return "test";
    }

}
```

And the view resolver...

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}
```

In this case, I expect the controller at domain.com/test to display "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/test.jsp". This seems to function fine on all my older projects but upon configuring this one, it won't cooperate and I keep getting a 404 error.

Any ideas why it cannot find the correct jsp file to display?

EDIT: Problem solved and solution is posted down below.

Comment: Your view resolver config seems fine. Are sure the controller getting called? Is the `System.out.println("Returning test.jsp");` prints anything? Also make sure that your possible `war` file contains the views.

Comment: The print is definitely happening, so it can't be the controller getting called.
Don't think the war file should make a difference as I'm merely launching through eclipse and the files exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.
As expected, it was something silly.

The issue was down to no Apache Tomcat dependency being present in pom.xml.
For future reference:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your controller in spring configuration?(`@ComponentScan` or `<context:component-scan .../>`)

Comment: Never had to do this before to be honest and it has always worked fine in the past without it. The controller is getting called so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: you could also check dispatcher mapping in web.xml or WebApplicationInitializer